# Temperature calculator isn't outputting correct temperature?

Tags: python

I've *tried* to make a temperature conversion calculator in python. Any help with what's wrong? I put in `20C`, and it's telling me that `20c=52f`, which I know isn't correct. Here's the code:

```
def convert(changeto,temp):
    if changeto == "c":
        converted = (5/9)*(temp-32)
        print '%d C =  %d F' % (temp,converted)
    elif changeto == "f":
        converted = (9/5)*(temp+32)
        print '%d F = %d C' % (temp, converted)
    else:
        print "Error, type C or F for Celsius or Fahrenheit conversions."

print "Temperature Converter"

temp = float(raw_input("Enter a temperature: "))
changeto = str(raw_input("Convert to (F)ahrenheit or (C)elsius? "))

convert(changeto,temp)

raw_input("Any key to exit")
```

Comment: 9/5 is always 1 .... try 9/5.0 instead

Comment: In addition to the floating point gotcha, you're adding 32 before multiplying when going from C to f. It should be `(9/5.0 * temp) + 32`. (Or `9/5.`, but I like the explicit `0` as a reminder.) Or, if you want integer math (truncating any decimal part), `((9 * temp) / 5) + 32` and `(5 * (temp - 32)) / 9`. Parens added for clarity.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper Thanks! That fixed it. I simply copied the formula I found on some python beginner problem website and didn't think twice about their math. Laziness bit me in the ass yet again, ah well.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your version of Python, `5/9` probably evaluates to zero. Change it to `5./9` (the dot turns the `5` into a [floating-point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point) literal).

The same goes for the other division.

On top of that, the two formulae you have are not inverses of one another and need to be re-examined.